# Closing the lid wakes laptop from sleep

Tags: systemd, suspend, laptop, acpi, sleep

Plugging the power cable in or removing it does the same. Expected behaviour would be that only opening the lid or pressing a key wakes it up. I disabled everything in /proc/acpi/wakeup, no change. Now I'm confused about ACPI and unsure what to look for in the logs.
Machine is a Lenovo T14 running Arch with Gnome. Any ideas where to go from here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm experiencing this with the same computer but Manjaro + KDE.

Comment: @hoyland I did, but I‘m unsure now what it was. Have you updated your BIOS?

Comment: I didn't update the bios, but I switched the BIOS 'sleep' setting from Windows to Linux, which seems to have fixed things.